# How to resume confirm user signup in cognito upon login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In my testing Cognito, I have run into an issue. In the case when a User Signs up, but abandons the confirmation step and then returns later to finish confirming there appears to be no way for this user to resume the confirmation process.

I can see the user I created in the user pool, but when I Sign in a `UserNotFoundException`(user does not exist) exception is raised.

I found an issue here related to the JS API (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/514#issuecomment-365470081):

> The user gets created in Cognito in the unconfirmed state.
>   Now I tried to log in with the same email and I am always receiving the UserNotFoundException. The expected result as per the docs should be UserNotConfirmedException so that I can ask the user to confirm the account.
>
> I am using the latest Js SDK

It looks like this affects the C# SDK as well. The C# SDK does possess this exception class: `Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.UserNotConfirmedException` It just appears not to be raised.

Is there anything special that needs to be configured to enable this exception to be raised on login?

I am using the following to send my request in the C# SDK

```
AuthFlowResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(
    srpRequest: new InitiateSrpAuthRequest
    {
        Password = password
    });
} 
catch(Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.UserNotConfirmedException e)
{
    // never catches here
}
catch(Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.UserNotFoundException e)
{
    // catches here
}
```

I have also opened a related Github issue here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/866

Comment: Hi AJ, any resolution or workaround for this?  I am running into the same problem with the SignUp API. If the user returns to try to sign up because they were previously interrupted before confirming the account.  Currently signUp throws UsernameExistsException instead of UserNotConfirmedException. Tested with Android SDK.

Comment: Following up on this, it looks like the SignIn API does throw UserNotConfirmedException correctly when using the Android SDK. Now, I'm hoping they will do the same for the SignUp API.

Comment: @RyanJones Unfortunately this has languished with AWS SDK team. I haven't really come up with a good workflow aside from "don't abandon sign up if your power goes out or network connectivity evaporates" =) It might only be solvable with a good support team with the training to know to delete accounts so the user can retry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call resendSignUp() again for to resume the verification . Note : Done call the signUp() function because the user is already registered

Answer (score 0):

You might not be seeing the `UserNotConfirmedException` exception because your app client is, by default, configured to be vague about auth errors. The documentation states that “this helps guard against credential-guessing attacks, providing additional security for your user pool.” See [Managing user existence error responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html).

You need to uncheck **Prevent user existence errors** on the app client configuration panel to allow the Cognito API to return more informative error codes and messages, such as `UserNotConfirmedException`.

[image: Edit app client information]